# gradient descent machine learning

Tags: python

I'm attending cousera class by Andrew Ng and I saw gradient descent with multiple variable. I'm trying to run gradient descent in python.These are my code in python

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

def gradient_descent(y_actual, alpha, iterations, m_current, b_current, x_dataset):
    if len(y_actual) != len(x_dataset):
        print(f"Dofferent lenght of input which is {len(y_actual)} and {len(x_dataset)}")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        pass
    m_current = m_current
    b_current = b_current
    m_derivative = 0
    b_derivative = 0
    new_m = []
    new_b = []
    itr = []
    for z in range(iterations):
        for i in range(len(x_dataset)):
            m_derivative += (y_actual[i] - ((m_current * x_dataset[i])+b_current))*x_dataset[i]
            b_derivative += (y_actual[i] - ((m_current * x_dataset[i]) + b_current))
        itr.append(z)
        m_current = m_current - (alpha*(m_derivative/len(x_dataset)))
        b_current = b_current - (alpha * (b_derivative / len(x_dataset)))
        new_m.append(m_current)
        new_b.append(b_current)
        m_derivative = 0
        b_derivative = 0
    return m_current, b_current, itr, new_m, new_b


m, b, iteration, m_history, b_history = gradient_descent([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 0.0001, 1000, 0, 0, [5, 8, 1, 4, 9, 3, 9, 8, 3, 5])

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(iteration, m_history)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(iteration,b_history)
plt.show()
```

I plot the iteration and relationship between the iteration and the decrease in b which is the intercept and relationship between the iteration and the decrease in m which is the coefficient. This is the graph that I get:

[image]

But the problem is that I saw a lot of graphs about gradient descent in Google like this:

[image]

What is the problem of my code that give me this result?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. Your gradients are negated. I know this because I randomly ran your code with the gradients negated and it worked. Note that you are subtracting the model's output in the cost function so you should multiply by negative one when you take the gradient (chain rule).
2. Your dataset is not well-represented by the linear model y = mx + b. Try making the x data points linear. A good sanity check is to generate your dataset from the model class that you use to fit it. Generate points from y = mx + b for some m and b and see if the algorithm can find m and b.

More directly to your question though, the graphs you generate are the model parameters while the one you show is the loss curve; there's no reason they should look similar. Actually, your graphs suggest exponential growth of the parameters, which is often caused by a sign error, as it was in your case. If you compute the error for each iteration, you can compare your graph to the loss curve you wish to see.